# Recreating indexes will improve performances

Tags: sql-server

I have few tables (base tables) which are getting inserted and updated twice a week. I have indexes created on these tables long back.

I'm applying logic on top of these tables in a stored procedure (without any parameter) and creating a final output table.

I'm scheduling this stored procedure twice a week using SQL Server agent job.

It is running slowly now (50 minutes) whereas if I run the stored procedure manually, it is running faster (15 - 18 minutes)

Do I have to drop the indexes whenever insert or update is happening in base tables and recreate it again after the insert or update?

If so do I have to do it every week?

What is its effect in performance of SQL Server agent jobs?

Comment: You should definitely not have to manually maintain the index after each data change. In fact you should only do it, if the index is very fragmented, and often used. It's difficult to give an exact answer because a lot of it depends on your exact situation, but I'd advice you to read up on the topic, perform some measurements and tests - and then form a strategy that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes do require maintenance, but the rate at which they do depends entirely on how much data is changed, and how those changes are ordered. You can google around for any number of scripts to check your index fragmentation, and how to defragment them. Usually even for larger databases, weekly or nightly maintenances are more than enough.

Anyway, the fact that the execution time differs depending on how you run it, points to two possible causes:

Parametrization, or the SET properties used by the connection.

If your procedure uses parameters but you run the script manually giving the parameters values as you do, then SQL Server knows exactly which values you're using, and can optimize the query execution to use the correct indexes etc on the spot. If your agent calls the procedure with the same parameters, then the process is different. SQL Server may not know which values are being used, so it has to use covering indexes or worse yet, even full on table scans (reading all the data in the whole table, rendering indexes useless) to make sure that it will find all the relevant data for the query. Google SQL Server parametrization, and you can find out more.

The set properties on the other hand control specific session properties that are applied automatically when you connect directly to the database via Management Studio. But when you use an agent job, that may not be the case. This can also result in a different plan which will take far more time.

Both these cases, depend on your database settings and the way your procedure works. So we have to guess here.

But typically, you need to set the following properties in the beginning of a script in an agent job to match the session properties used in your regular Management Studio session:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
```

All of the terms here can be googled. I suggest you do so. Those articles can explain these things far better than I've the time for, especially given that - no disrespect intended - you're relatively new to SQL Server. So explaining these things with a suitable terminology here, is difficult. :)